# Oracle SERIAL# changing for the same SID

Tags: oracle, sid

I'm using Oracle19c with a thin client and I'd like to set traces on the 5 application connections with
EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_sql_trace_in_session(sid, serial#, true ) so I created a stored procedure.

When I select the SID and SERIAL# with:

select sid, serial#, osuser, machine, program, module, username
from v$session WHERE username IS NOT NULL  ORDER BY username ASC;

I noticed that the SERIAL# keeps changing every minute or so, but I don't have any connection timeout set for the user: it's using the DEFAULT profile and LIMIT='UNLIMITED'.

Is there a way to "extend the life" of those connections?

Answer (score 0):

A new serial# is a new session. This probably means the application doing the connecting is diconnecting/reconnecting, possibly by design at regular intervals, or possibly by error and its dropping the connection and recovering by commencing a new one.

But you'll need to look inside the app to see that, not the database.

If you want to trace such an app, you could create a LOGON trigger to turn on trace as soon as they connect, rather than trying to catch it with a query to v$session, eg

```
create or replace
trigger TRACE_ALL_LOGINS
after logon on MY_DB_ACCOUNT.schema
begin
    execute immediate 'alter session set tracefile_identifier = BLAH';
    execute immediate 'alter session set events = ''10046 trace name context forever, level 12''';
exception
  when others then null;
end;
/
```

I keep the when-others-then-null in this special case to ensure that if the trigger fails for some reason, we don't block the ability to connect at all.